# How to access the REMOTE_ADDR property in nlog.config in an asp.net web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, nlog

I have a asp.net web service application (asmx). NLog has been configured on the project. I want to add the caller's ip address in the logfile. I need to access the REMOTE_ADDR property from within the nlog config file. This is what I tried.

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
          layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${callsite} ${asp-request:item=REMOTE_ADDR} ${message}"
          fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log" />
```

the renderer **${asp-request:item=REMOTE_ADDR}** should have done the trick. But nothing happens. What am I missing?

Note : I have added reference to the NLog.Extended.dll to the project.

Any help would be appreciated, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably worked it out by now, but the code you were looking for is:

> ```
> ${aspnet-request:serverVariable=remote_addr}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I had solved the issue by setting a nlog context variable with the caller IP and using that in the nlog.config file. I'll later go back and see if this works

Comment: Siddharth - how did you get it working? Care to share!

Answer (score 0):

As a side note using:

```
${ aspnet-request:serverVariable = remote_addr }
```

Produced the following error:

> LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'aspnet-request'
>
> You have to install NLog.Web to make this work.